# InAppPurchase in Jailbroken device

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, itunes, sandbox, jailbreak

Can we test InAppPurchase(sandbox testing) from jailbroken device? Is there any connection between iTunes update and InAppPurchase testing?(means can't we test InAppPurchase sandbox testing if we have older version of iTunes.)

Comment: there is no connection between the jailbreaking and the `InAppPurchase` process. no matter what kind of device initiates the purchasing, the main point is the Apple account (or test account) must have been set up correctly on the current device, otherwise the purchase won't be successful.

Comment: what about this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600424/inapppurchase-stop-receiving-the-productrequest-response-after-deleting-and-rein and even am getting list of InAppPurchase items in simulator but not on my jailbreak device.

Comment: no worries.... it works on jailbreak too, just need to remove Appsync from that device.

Comment: I don't that link. I've said my personal experience of it because one of my test devices is jailbroken, and I had no problem during testing the `InAppPurchase`, however, I don't have Cydia or any third part application on that device, it is just jailbroken for the testing especially.

Answer (score 2):

no worries... it works on jailbreak too, just need to remove Appsync from that device

Comment: It's correct for me, just go to Cydia and remove AppSync. Thank stack.